# How to pass multiple Flags into the IMAP.?

Tags: imap

I am working on MailClient and I want to set Multipal Flags for Eg. SEEN, UNSEEN so how I can set in C#,
I had pass this command like this but it will give me error. like BAD command.
so the my command like this. 
      byte[] commandBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes((@"$ UID SEARCH UNSEEN \SEEN" + "\r\n"));

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use backslash, this is the correct request:

```
A000 UID SEARCH SEEN UNSEEN
```

Are you sure you want write you own IMAP client from scrach? There are some opensource libraries, as well as paid ones (My [Mail.dll IMAP component](http://www.lesnikowski.com/blog/index.php/how-to-search-imap-in-net/) for example).

Comment: +1 for Don't Reinvent the Wheel, especially if you are not a domain expert.